# Bringing added layer to front by default using QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers

In QGIS, is there a way to bring a new layer automatically in front of all other layers when the layer order panel is active?

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "a new layer"? One created manually? The output of some tools? "In front of all other layers" means: "On top of the other layers in the layer stack"?

Comment: anytime I create or add a new layer (any layer type), the layer order panel put it at the bottom of the list so behind all other layers. So I have to move it manually at the top of the list if i want to see it on the map